# Why does the Java mapFactory argument of the method toMap in the Collectors class need the types to be specified?

Tags: java, types, java-stream, collectors, java-14

The following code does not compile with my JDK14:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = Arrays.asList("this", "is", "just", "an", "example").stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(w -> w.length(),
                              w -> w,
                            (existing, replacement) -> replacement,
                            () -> new TreeMap<>(Comparator.reverseOrder())));
```

while if I specify the types for the constructor of the TreeMap it works fine:

```
Map<Integer, String> map4 = Arrays.asList("this", "is", "just", "an", "example").stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(w -> w.length(),
                              w -> w,
                            (existing, replacement) -> replacement,
                            () -> new TreeMap<Integer, String>(Comparator.reverseOrder())));
```

Am I missing something or is there a bug in the type erasure system of JDK14?

Comment: Is the error message from the compiler something like "Cannot derive type"?

Comment: Yes, "cannot infer type-variable(s)".

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is an issue with inferring type for `Comparator` in case of chained calls.

It could work if you create a map supplier beforehand (btw, not only in JDK14):

```
Supplier<Map<Integer, String>> supplier = () -> new TreeMap<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());

Map<Integer, String> mapWithSupplier = Arrays.asList("this", "is", "just", "an", "example").stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(w -> w.length(),
                        w -> w,
                        (existing, replacement) -> replacement,
                        supplier));
```

If you used `Collections.reverseOrder()`, you would not encounter this issue at all:

```
Map<Integer, String> mapCollectionReversed = Arrays.asList("this", "is", "just", "an", "example").stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(w -> w.length(),
                        w -> w,
                        (existing, replacement) -> replacement,
                        () -> new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder())));
```

or at least created a comparator beforehand:

```
Comparator<Integer> comparator = Comparator.reverseOrder();

Map<Integer, String> mapWithComparator = Arrays.asList("this", "is", "just", "an", "example").stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(w -> w.length(),
                        w -> w,
                        (existing, replacement) -> replacement,
                        () -> new TreeMap<>(comparator)));
```

---

And without `reverseOrder` the map could be created successfully with `TreeMap::new`:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = Arrays.asList("this", "is", "just", "an", "example").stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(w -> w.length(),
                        w -> w,
                        (existing, replacement) -> replacement,
                        TreeMap::new));
```

Comment: OK, but the question is why the Java compiler cannot infer the type of the TreeMap. It does when one passes the reference to the constructor, as in your example.

Comment: It seems there is an issue with inferring type of comparator when it's passed to the map constructor - please check the update

Comment: With the more recents versions of the JDK the compiler can infer the type, so the question can now be closed.